# Hibernate: eagerly fetching depth limit

Tags: hibernate, fetch

suppose i have a table named Products which is self-joined using a foreign key: parent_product_id -> id. Now in the corresponding hibernate Products model i got a Set which is consisted of all the child products of *this* product. Fetch mode is set to EAGER because i want to get all the children products of *this* product when *this* product is fetched. But, the thing is, i dont want to get all the children's children (grandsons of *this* product) or children's children's children (great-grandsons of *this* product), which is what i get with the EAGER fetching. I just want the first ones - just the first children of *this* product. It is like the Product should be first fetched eagerly, then it should switch to lazy fetching. What should i do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting max_fetch_depth but this may not be the best solution. You may want to consider some alternate approaches, for example maybe not actually using EAGER in this scenario. Have you had a look at the Hibernate forum? This is quite a common topic. Maybe have a look at this [thread](https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=956249&start=0).